# Explain tag numbers in profile?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, profile-page

See screenshot of tags on my profile at Super User:

[image]

*What do the numbers on either side of the tag mean?* e.g. 53 `Windows-7` x 83

Comment: try hovering for the tooltip ...

Comment: @waffles: I am confused by the tooltip.  See my comment on RegDwight's answer.

Comment: see the faq on meta for score definition ... it is the total number of upvotes minus total number of downvotes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right number is the number of questions+answers you've posted with the tag. Left number is your total vote count received on non-wiki answers to questions with those tags.

Answer (score 6):

The number to the right should be self-explanatory, thanks to the ×. Tag times X = you have asked/answered X questions with that tag. The number to the left is more confusing, but that's why it is actually explained in great detail in a mouseover tooltip.